# convert a date in pig from YYYY-mm-dd to YYYYmmDD

Tags: regex, apache-pig

The issue is there are nulls in this column, how do i handle the nulls while converting a date from 2016-01-01 to 20160101

[image]

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(Del_EFF_DT,'\\d{4}\\d{2}\\d{2}\\s',1) AS DEL_EFF_DT;
```

however the results are coming up as all null when i dump that filed

```
s = foreach final generate DEL_EFF_DT;
dump s;
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you simply replace all dashes by empty strings?

Comment: @sp00m yes that would thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes as @spoom has mentioned

```
REPLACE(Del_EFF_DT,'-','') AS DEL_EFF_DT;
```

This would solve the issues

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression for a formatted date seems redundant. The date will always be in the same format, so if your goal is to remove the dashes, just replace them with nothing. Running regular expression is more resource intensive anyway.

I have been programming for 6 years and have never needed regular expressions. There is almost always another way to do what you need to do. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The below sample snippet can be used while dealing with null values

```
test=  LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') as(A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray); 
values = FOREACH test GENERATE A==''?'null':(A is null?'null':A)) as A,(B==''?'null':(B is null?'null':B)) as B,(C==''?'null':(C is null?'null':C)) as C;
```